# Python statsmodels WLS (weighted least squares) error independent of weights

Tags: python, curve-fitting, statsmodels, data-fitting

I'm using Python's statsmodels to perform a weighted linear regression.  Since this is my first time with this module, I ran some basic tests.

Doing these, I find that estimated errors on the parameters (i.e., uncertainties) are independent of the weight.

This doesn't fit my naive expectation (that larger error bars would produce a more uncertain result), or the definition I've seen in nonlinear fitting, which generally uses the **weighted** Hessian to report the uncertainty of the parameters.

I couldn't find an explicit description of the calculation of the parameter-errors (either in the statsmodels docs or support pages).  Posting here to see if anyone has experience with this (and for future searchers).

Minimal code:

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

escale = 1

xvals = np.arange(1,11)
yvals = xvals**2                         # dummy nonlinear y-data
evals = escale*np.sqrt(yvals)            # errorbars

X = sm.add_constant(xvals)               # to get intercept term
model = sm.WLS(yvals, X, 1.0/evals**2)   # weight inverse to error
result = model.fit()

print "escale = ", escale
print "fit = ", result.params
print "err = ", result.bse          # same value independent of escale
```

So is this a numerical bug in statsmodels, or PEBKAC (i.e., is this correct behavior and my expectations are wrong)?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Parameter uncertainty intervals definitely depend on the weights.

Comment: Actually I just ran your code. I get different values for `fit` and `err` depending on `escale`. Maybe also show some example output for different `escale` values, and add statsmodels and numpy version used.

Comment: Thanks @FabianRost - Code is corrected to reproduce the problem.  Uncertainties are numerically identical across multiple values of `escale` now.